# Where to place an "add new record" item for a listview?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I'm working on an app that has a listview, and I need a way to add rows to the listview. The code is not a problem, but I'm just wondering if there is a convention or consistent android UI design for that?

I'm unsure if I should use a row at index 0 that when longclicked could add a new record, or if generally an "add new record" button is added as a context item, or what.

Does anyone know what is usually done, or have any great ideas for how to handle this?

Thank you much

Comment: Hey u can add at the end of listview... just display the list in one layout and add button in another layout below listview. That seems much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add button with standart android icon (located in sdk..) to ActionBar.
Also you should add compatibility library to use ActionBar on devices prior to Android 3.0

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this (even a few months late.) Looking back in my code I see that this is very close to what I did, and is good advice.